# type annotation for return type of method where that depends on an attribute of the class

Tags: python

Say I have:

```py
class A: pass
class B: pass

class Foo:

  factory: Type = A

   def make(self) -> ?:
       return self.factory()


class Bar(Foo):

   factory: Type = B
```

What type annotation do I use on make to indicate that the type returned is that of the `factory` attribute?

Comment: `def make(self) -> A`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [generics](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Generic).

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Generic, Type

T = TypeVar('T')


class A:
    pass


class B:
    pass


class GenericFooerBarrer(Generic[T]):
    factory: Type[T]

    def make(self) -> T:
        return self.factory()


class Foo(GenericFooerBarrer[A]):
    factory: Type[A] = A


class Bar(GenericFooerBarrer[B]):
    factory: Type[B] = B
```

To match exactly as you wanted you would of want a default type for generic such that `Foo` is generic with default.
[Generic default](https://peps.python.org/pep-0696/) is only planned for python 3.12, so you'll have to wait just a bit.

Comment: I mean, you can use python 3.12 even now, but it is in prerelease...

Comment: Are generic defaults available in the typing extensions backport thingy?

Comment: @ChrisWithers Actually, now I checked an it seems the answer is yes! That is exciting. https://github.com/python/typing_extensions/commit/fafb5c597f586e8109a1c668c706264060f5456a